# Magento 2 Cron Script Execute From CLI

Tags: magento2, cron, magento2.2.2, cli

How can I execute my cron class in command line especially for testing ?

Normally one could `php -f myfile.php`

OR

Calling a class method:
`php -r 'include "/path/to/file.php"; ClassName::MethodName();'`

I have a Cron class and would like to test it in command line to display E.G: 'Hello World!?

Answer (score 2):

**Run cron from the command line**
Command options:

```
$  bin/magento cron:run [--group="<cron group name>"]
```

Like 
    $ php bin/magento cron:run --group="customgroupname_cron"

where --group specifies the cron group to run (omit this option to run cron for all groups)

To run the indexing cron job, enter:

```
bin/magento cron:run --group index
```

To run the default cron job, enter:

```
bin/magento cron:run --group default
```